# How to pass the values from accessed database to the new formed database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

My project is to create an emenu.For this I have created a database in phpmyadmin.The menu has been accessed by using code below.And now I want to send that menu item to a new database(that has been already created) on clicking the button "add to cart".I cannot seem to find a way to pass the value as a variable.i.e.name,price in this code. This is my code:

```
    class Appetizers(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller=controller 

        def insdb():
    cro=mysql.connector.connect(user='k***',password='***',host='******',database='newdb')
        mycursor=cro.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO order_frm_client(name,quantity,price) VALUES(name,2,price)""" )
        cro.commit()

    conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='k***',password='***',host='*****',database='menu')
    mycursor=conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM APPETIZERS")
    results=mycursor.fetchall()

    yo=50
    for row in results:
        id=row[0]
        name=row[1]
        price=row[3]

        listBox = Listbox(self, height=1,width=40,highlightcolor="red")
        listBox.place(x=100,y=yo)
        listBox.insert(END,name)
        listBox1 = Listbox(self, height=1,width=10,highlightcolor="red")
        listBox1.place(x=350,y=yo)
        listBox1.insert(END,price)

        spin=Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=10, width=10).place(x=420,y=yo)
        button=Button(self, text='Add to Cart',width=4, command=insdb(name,price))
        button.place(x=500,y=yo)
        yo=yo+30
```

Comment: `insdb` should be `Appetizers.insdb`. And the method definition is missing the parameters. Your indentation is all messed up, that's critical in Python code.

Comment: Look up how to do prepared statements in Python to pass parameters to queries.

Comment: Are the 2 databases located in the same mysql server?